# Solr query with filter query

Tags: solr, solr6

I need to handle suggestion using solr query. Suggestion is working fine. But the problem is that suggestions are conditional i.e. suggestions are based on geo locations. I want the following  equivalent query:

```
q=<SEARCH TERM>&fq=country:"<search country>"
```

I have tried some approaches but they are not working. What is the way to handle such scenarios?

Edit 1:
Suggester Config:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent"> 
<lst name="suggester"> 
<str name="name">mySuggester</str> 
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str> 
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str> 
<str name="field">autofill</str> 
<str name="contextField">allowed_location</str> 
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_autofill</str> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str> 
<str name="storeDir">path on file system</str> 
</lst> 
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the country field is indexed in solr?
Also, you need the equivalent of the query in which language? Like a java solrj API call?

Comment: yes country is indexed in solr. I am using solr admin console to verify. I believe if i can trigger query using solr console , it can be done in any language. Additional Info: I can get the result using select handler. But the result won't be suggestions. I want to get the result using suggest handler

Comment: kindly show us the code for suggest handler and cou ntry field schema

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure the suggester component in your solrconfig.xml qnd your suggestions queries need to be of the below form(shortened)

```
suggest.q=<search_term>&suggest.cfq=<search_country>
```

If you need the filtering query to work on country field, it must be configured as a **contextField** in your solrconfig.xml

For better understanding please refer to the reference guide [link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html#Suggester-ContextFiltering)

Comment: I will try this solution and will discuss after that

Comment: I tried the suggestion and got error. I am using solr 6.6 . It says context is not supported by this suggester

Comment: My suggester config is:
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">autofill</str>
    <str name="contextField">allowed_location</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_autofill</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="storeDir">path on file system</str> 
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

Comment: suggester stack trace

{
  "error":{
    "msg":"this suggester doesn't support contexts",
    "trace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: this suggester doesn't support contexts\n\tat org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.AnalyzingSuggester.build(AnalyzingSuggester.java:404)\n\tat at  
at <more lines in stack trace> ,
    "code":500}}

Comment: field definition for allowed_location
<field name="allowed_location" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" />